# create-next-app fails when run in container

Tags: docker, next.js

I want to create a new nextjs app in my current directory on the host, but without installing node etc. So I run a container like this

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/app node:17.8.0 bash
```

`whoami` shows that I'm root in the container. Then I run these commands in the container

```
cd /app
npx create-next-app@latest
```

and get this output

```
Need to install the following packages:
  create-next-app@latest
Ok to proceed? (y) y
sh: 1: create-next-app: Permission denied
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 8.5.5 -> 8.6.0
npm notice Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v8.6.0
npm notice Run npm install -g npm@8.6.0 to update!
npm notice
```

I don't understand why I get permission denied, since I'm root.

It has something to do with the volume mapping of the host directory, because if I run the container without the volume mapping, the command works.

The permissions in the host directory look like this

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 hans hans 4096 Apr  9 10:35 .
drwxrwxr-x 11 hans hans 4096 Apr  9 10:21 ..
```

Why does it fail and how can I get it to work?

Comment: even if you do it with root, then you have trouble editing it with your own user later. Better run the container with your uid `docker run -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" ...`

Comment: That's true. I just `chown` on the host after the files have been created. The weird thing is that running it with my UID/GID actually solves the issue. I don't understand why that makes a difference, but if you change your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: It may have to do with this kind of stuff. https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/. I dont know much about it but I know there are some ways to remap ids. Sometimes everything is shifted upwards by a fixed number.

Comment: That error sounds to me like the newly-installed `create-next-app` script doesn't have execute permission, more than any user-ID-related problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze It only fails when I run it in the volume-mapped directory. If it was because it was missing the execute permission, I'd think it'd always fail, no matter what directory it was run in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to run the container right away with the correct UID/GID, so that you don't have to fix the permissions later on. This might also solve the initial problem.

```
docker run -u "$(id -u):$(id -g)" ...
```